# "Silver lining [of a cloud]" en français

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

Je cherche des proverbes et expressions idiomatiques traduisant l'idiome anglais courant "silver lining of a [dark] cloud", indiquant un aspect positif d'une situation autrement considérée négative.

Cet idiome se retrouve souvent dans le proverbe "Every cloud has a silver lining", mais peut aussi parfois s'utiliser seul (e.g. "The silver lining in this situation is that...").

Une rapide recherche sur Google suggère seulement "Après la pluie le beau temps" qui me semble un contresens total.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selon le cas particulière et le contexte, je veux deux moyens de s'en sortir :

- Retomber sur le proverbe **« à quelque chose malheur est bon »**. C'est une phrase complète, donc ça peut être délicat dans une traduction qui se voudrait courte de *silver lining*. Mais c'est le proverbe français le plus proche à mon sens.
- Utiliser des expressions comme **« le côté positif de la chose »**, « le bon côté des choses », « la lueur d'espoir », « le point positif », « l'éclaircie à l'horizon », etc.

Comment: _Il faut voir le bon côté des choses_ est aussi celui qui me paraît le plus naturel.

Comment: Ca vaut peut-être la peine de noter que l'expression « le revers de la médaille » ressemble, mais a la connotation inverse.

Comment: Merci pour les suggestions. J'espérai trouver une tournure véritablement idiomatique (comparable à la version anglaise), mais il semble qu'il n'y en ait pas vraiment. Étrange...

Comment: @Dave: « le bon côté des choses » **est** très idiomatique.

Answer (score 2):

On peut parler de la *contrepartie*.

> La contrepartie de cette situation est...

Par contre j'ai un doute entre *contrepartie à* et *contrepartie de*.

Comment: [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contrepartie+de%2Ccontrepartie+%C3%A0&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) et [exemples dans la définition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/contrepartie)